# What is the trend of Symmetric and Skew Symmetric Matrices raised to Even and Odd Integral Powers? (W.r.t. Being Symmetric or Skew-Symmetric)

Tags: linear-algebra

Please explain

1. **All** positive integral powers of a *Symmetric Matrix* gives a **Symmetric Matrix.**
2. **Odd** positive integral powers of a *Skew-Symmetric Matrix* give a **Skew-Symmetric** Matrix.
3. **Even** positive integeral powers of *Skew-Symmetric Matrix* give a **Symmetric** Matrix.

Comment: It would be better for you if you could show your approach.

Comment: Use the identity $(AB)^t=B^tA^t$.

Comment: @BAYMAX But in this case it is justified because for the proof we can use similar technique..what you have presented..

Comment: @Widawensen ok, my apologies.

Comment: @BAYMAX Interesting why this question was "put on hold" ? (and heavily down-voted) Maybe it's easy but what else is wrong with it  ? - just a question ..

Comment: @Widawensen Yes i too agree,but can we do anything about it,i am little unaware of the technicalities regarding MSE.Also this may demotivate the user from asking questions freely!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A$ is the square matrix of order say $m$,then Observe that $(A^{n})^{t} = (A^{t})^{n}$ ,

so for your first case for Symmetric matrices $A^{t} = A$ , so 
$A^{n} = A.A.A.....A$ , $n$ times $= A^{t}.A^{t}.A^{t}....A^{t}$ , $n$ times $=(A^{t})^{n} = (A^{n})^{t}$.so $A^{n}$ is symmetric for any positive integer $n$.

For the second case also since $A^{t} = -A$,so $(A^{t})^{n} = -A.-A.-A....-A$ $n$ times,$=(-1)^{n} . (A)^{n}$ so if $n$ is odd it will be skew-symmetric and for $n$ even it will be symmetric.Hope this helps!